# Truncating folder names after first space

Tags: ubuntu, directory, rename, mv

i have a directory full of sub-directories with names like

- 01 - title of folder
- 02 - second title
- 03 - etc
- 04 - etc
  .
  .
  .
- 30 - final folder

i want to truncate all of these folder names to just be the numbers so they would appear like so:

- 01
- 02
- 03

is there a way to write a script or a simple command that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Perl-based rename utility (which appears to be what Ubuntu
provides), you could do the renaming operation like this (replacing
`*` with whichever list of directories you actually want):

```
rename 's/^(\S+).*/$1/' *
```

(I suggest using `rename -n` at first to see what would be done before
actually renaming anything.)

The replacement string asks to match a sequence of non-space
characters (`\S+`) at the start (`^`) of the original file name,
followed by anything (`.*`), and replacing it with the first matched
group (`$1`), which was the initial space-free segment.

Comment: this worked perfectly thanks! is there a document somewhere that shows all the string commands? the ^(\S+) etc

Comment: The syntax used by this version of the rename command is that of Perl regular expressions; you can access its documentation using `man perlre` if installed on your system, or e.g. at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html